# If option selected, add/remove multiple attributes from multiple fields with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes, field

I have a select box at the top of a form that basically hides or displays another section of the form depending on what is selected. By default 'No' is selected, and my form validation works for the sections of the form displayed.

I am trying to validate this section of the form that is unhidden when 'Yes' is selected, and so require attributes for the fields of this section to either added or removed (whichever way works best) depending on the option selection. This is because the form can be submitted without the hidden section, but if this section is unhidden then I want to validate the fields.

My select field:

```
<select name="Joint" class="input-select" onChange="javascript:fieldsApp2(this);">
        <option value="No" selected="selected" >No</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
```

Example of fields without the validation attributed (when 'No' is selected):

```
<label class='fieldlabel'>First name:</label>
<div class='field'>
<input type="text" name="Forename" class="input-text">
</div>

<label class='fieldlabel'>Last name:</label>    
<div class='field'>
<input type="text" name="Surname" class="input-text">
</div>
```

The same fields but with the validation attributes required when 'Yes' selected:

```
<label class='fieldlabel'>First name:</label>
<div class='field'>
<input type="text" name="Forename" class="input-text" data-required="true" data-error-message="Valid First Name recquired.>
</div>

<label class='fieldlabel'>Last name:</label>    
<div class='field'>
<input type="text" name="Surname" class="input-text" data-required="true" data-error-message="Valid Last Name recquired.>
</div>
```

So I guess I'm looking for a way to use jQuery to switch between these two! I'm really not jQuery savvy unfortunately.
Any help would really be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Do you have any [**code you attempted**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) at all which is giving you trouble? If so, can you please post it so  we can have a look at it to see why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('[name="Joint"]').on('change', function() {
        var state     = this.value == 'Yes',
            data_obj1 = {'data-required'      : ( state ? 'true':'' ), 
                         'data-error-message' : ( state ? 'Valid First Name required.' : '') },
            data_obj2 = {'data-required'      : ( state ? 'true':'' ), 
                         'data-error-message' : ( state ? 'Valid Last Name required.' : '') };

        $('[name="Forename"]').attr(data_obj1);
        $('[name="Surname"]').attr(data_obj2);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fwKyx/)

This should toggle the data attributes based on the selects value.

Using `data()` is usually the way to go, but that does'nt really change the attribute value, so not sure if that would work or not ?

Comment: Nice answer...definitely more efficient than what I was coming up with.. +1

Comment: Needed to work out some kinks in a fiddle, but now it seems like it's working just fine. Thanks!

Comment: This looks really good!! I have about 6 fields I need to apply this to so I'll play around and try to get this working. What an amazing response time @adeneo!

Comment: @adeneo this might be a stupid question but where should this code go? I've put it in a separate file and included it as a script in the header but nothing changes. Is there somewhere I can contact you? Thanks so much

Comment: @Jambo - You'll have to add jQuery before the js file containing this code, and it needs to be wrapped in DOM ready. I'll add that to the answer now!

Comment: @adeneo this is driving me crazy :( I've been trying to get it work for hours, I really don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, although I havent tested it.

```
//Fires each time the dropdown is changed
$(".input-select[name='Joint']").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "Yes") {
        $(".input-text").attr({
           data-required: true,
           data-error-message: "Valid name required." //You may have to set both fields individually if you want 2 different messages.
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".input-text").removeAttr("data-required data-error-message");
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem was about getting the required parameters, you can select elements by data attributes like this:

```
$("input[data-required='true']")
```

That way you can get the list of elements, that need validation. jQuery [data() method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) will help you adding those required attributes dynamically.